# Comparing two S3 Buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two AWS S3 buckets, lets say B1 and B2. I upload images to B1 and there is a lambda function that is triggered when an image is uploaded to B1, then the image is compressed to generate a thumbnail, and lastly, that image is uploaded to the second bucket B2. So basically the bucket B2 will have all the images which are in B1 but having a compressed version of the images. Something like this

```
       B1                  B2
image1.jpg (2MB)    image1.jpg(224KB)
image2.jpg (4MB)    image2.jpg(428KB)
image3.jpg (3MB)    image3.jpg(312KB)
```

Now I want to check whether the compression was done properly or not. To do that I plan to use a python script to check if the file names of the images in both buckets are exactly the same and the images in B2 have sizes in KB or have a smaller size than those in B1. Could anyone suggest is my approach correct or is there any other way I could test it?

Comment: Sounds good. If you have a _huge_ number of images (eg tens of thousands), you might want to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, in the lambda function, you have configured to save the thumbnail image in B2 with the same name, I believe this solution should work.

Else, if checking the compression works is the primary objective, just checking the overall bucket size instead of going at the object level would work as well (provided the 2 buckets have exactly same objects).